# C# 4.0 how to pass variables to threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

How would i pass some parameters to a new thread that runs a function from another class ?
What i'm trying to do is to pass an array or multiple variables to a function that sits in another class and its called by a new thread.

i have tried to do it like this >

```
    Functions functions = new Functions();

    string[] data;

    Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(functions.Post()));

    th.Start(data);
```

but it shows error "No overload for method 'Post' takes 0 arguments"

Any ideas ?

Comment: please note that the real problem with your code is that you are calling the Post method instead of passing it into the delegate constructor. You should leave out the parentheses after functions.Post() and this will compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have this flagged C# 4, the new approach to this would be:

```
Functions functions = new Functions();

string[] data = GetData();

Task.Factory.StartNew( () => functions.Post(data) );
```

---

If you really want to leave this using a dedicated thread, and not the Task Parallel library, you can.  Given your comments, it sounds like `Post()` is probably defined as `Post(string[] data)`.  This will not work since `ParameterizedThreadStart` expects the method to be `Post(object data)`.

You can work around this via lambdas and using [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) instead of ParameterizedThreadStart, however, without changing your methods:

```
Functions functions = new Functions();
string[] data = GetData();
Thread th = new Thread( () =>
    {
        functions.Post(data);
    });
th.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is :

```
 new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(functions.Post/*(remove)*/));
```

and Functions.Post should be of the form:

```
 void Post(object state) { string[] data = (string[]) state; .... }
```

If you already have a fixed `void Post(string[] data)` you could add a wrapper to the Functions class:

```
 void Post2(object state) { Post((string[]) state); }
```

But when using Fx4 you should really take a look at the Task library.

Comment: now i get "No overload for 'Post' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'"

Comment: @Aviatrix: Can you post your code (or at least the sig.) for functions.Post()?

Comment: @Aviatrix, I was still editing a little, maybe the last version helps. But I'm with Reed here, please post the outlines.

Comment: The problem is most likely that "Post" doesn't take an object, but rather a string[], as it's parameter....